# Payone Creditcard Problem and IWD Onestepcheckout

Tags: magento-1.7

I'm using the IWD Onestepcheckout extension in combination with PAYONE (3.1.3). And I can't get PAYONEs payment method "Credit Card" to work.

The check of credit card data is always performed twice. The first time the system always throws an error "Parameter {} cardexpiredate faulty or missing", even though the expiration date is ok.

I suspect there is something wrong with the Javascript that does the data validation. But I can't figure out where exactly the problem occurs. I have contacted the developers, but because this problem is caused by the conflict of extensions, they were not able to help.

I'm working on Magento CE 1.7.0.2.

Any hints on how to solve this would be appreciated.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about third party modules support. And on the side note, don't use IWD checkout mainly because of this: http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/8460/146

Comment: Detailed answer you can find [here](http://razbakov.com/magento/2015/07/15/iwd-one-page-checkout-and-payone-credit-card.html).

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to address the checkout and alter the way the payments are  processed there as Payone will make ajax calls for CC data validation and uses this to validate the payment later. Validation functionality depends on checkout/onepage process and if IWD OneStepCheckout process is different then it will fail and has to be adjusted