# Magento one page checkout with iwd credit card infor gets deleted on update

Tags: onepage-checkout

I am using magento onepage checkout iwd extension.(http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/one-page-checkout.html)
My issue is after filling all info regarding credit card etc..if user changes anything from shipping form like zipcode ,state etc..page updates and credit card information are not there.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using this module and not another one? I have only heard horror stories about this module.

Answer (score 2):

Yes I have similar issues and other problems with this module.

Don't use this module. It is too buggy. Spend the modest amount of money for an OPC module that works well and is fully supported.

Comment: I might add [this motive](http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/8460/146) to the list of reasons not to use the IWD extension.