# Magento important message notification disable

Tags: error

How to disable notification Important: Please setup IWD_ALL in order to finish IWD One Page Checkout installation.Please download IWD_ALL and setup it via Magento Connect in magento?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a third party module support.

Answer (score 1):

It seams like you installed one of the IWD extensions. Most probably this replaced the default notification toolbar.
In order to get rid of it, you can check the code to see where these notifications are coming from and disable it.

Or you can contact the developer for this.

But as a future reference, do not use the IWD extensions, mainly because of this: [Hidden values in an extension - encode decode data transaction](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/8460/146).

If they "phone home" from one extension most probably they do the same for the others. This is bad....their website is down, your website is most probably down or the extensions stop working.

Answer (score 0):

You have installed `IWD One page checkout extension` and to make it work you need to install `IWD_ALL extension` too which is available here to [download](http://www.google.com/url?q=http%3A%2F%2Fiwdextensions.com%2Fmedia%2Fmodules%2Fiwd_all.tgz&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNGnp5L8-iiXt4MVdwEKfLDRzBeU7A) .

Download it and `MERGE` the folders into your root folder later Logout and relogin clear the cache refresh the indexes.

Comment: Thanks,ttell me particularly in which folder it would be merged? give me the path.

Comment: after downloading unzip the iwd_all folder now copy the files `app`,`js`,`skin` now goto your root folder(your `magento` running folder) just paste there it ask for `merge` select that.