# Add custom styleshet to IWD one page checkout module

Tags: layout, onepage-checkout, css

I've installed IWD Onepage Checkout, and I'm trying to style it.

Rather than edit the 'core' installation, I want to add my own stylesheet -

I've added this to `/app/design/frontend/default/<theme>/layout/local.xml`

```
<opc_index_index>
    <action method="addCss">
        <stylesheet>css/custom-opc.css</stylesheet>
    </action>
</opc_index_index>
```

..however, my stylesheet isn't getting added?

Comment: Don't use IWD checkout. Mostly because of this: http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/8460/146

Comment: @Marius - why have you deleted my answer and added it to the question? I'm usually on SO, this isn't the norm. over there...?

Comment: The answer section is for answers only. Your "answer" looked like an edit. If it wasn't an edit, make it look like an answer.

Comment: the answer was that i forgot my reference.... the solution was the newly posted code

Comment: have edited the answer. please undelete it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is the correct one, i think the identifier `<opc_index_index>` might be wrong. Double check the extension XML to see how is the extension adding the CSS to the OPC pag. Also flush your cache since XMLs are often cached.

Comment: Super, remember to mark the question as resolved if it is.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out why it wasn't working.

I forgot to add my reference.

Here's the working excerpt

```
<opc_index_index>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addCss">
            <stylesheet>css/custom.css</stylesheet>
        </action>
    </reference>
</opc_index_index>
```

I'm still very new to magento, so not sure *why* this works....